# The interface between the abstract assembly instructions and the physical electrical logic in the processor

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture, binary, compiler

I just learned that there is an  interface between the abstract assembly instructions and the physical electrical logic in the processor. Can someone please explain that interface to me ?(I Hope I asked right question this time)

Comment: That question makes no sense, the compiler is a program running on the abstraction level of these 1s and 0s

Comment: I could not ask it properly as I am in very early stage of learning it . But if I say like this " What really a mp3 file contain?" then what would be answer.

Comment: If you see this answer of "photon" ...  my question is related to this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25075/how-is-binary-converted-to-electrical-signals?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Your question is as useful as asking "how does multiplication convert the numbers into chemical signals inside my head". It is the result of an abstract algorithm working on abstract data. It doesn't matter how they are represented, and algorithm does always the same to the same data.

Comment: I think I have to know microprocessor better.  :(

Comment: "What the file contains" depends on where you are looking at it. "MP3 file on disk" and "MP3 file on Flash" and "MP3 file in memory" and "MP3 file being transmitted over internet" are all *physically* very different objects. But the representation can be interpreted as the same set of 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Digitizaion

> Digitization, less commonly known as digitalization, is the process of converting information into a digital (i.e. computer-readable) format, in which the information is organized into bits. The result is the representation of an object, image, sound, or signal (usually an analog signal) by generating a series of numbers that describe a discrete set of its points or samples. The result is called digital representation or, more specifically, a digital image, for the object, and digital form, for the signal. In modern practice, the digitized data is in the form of binary numbers, which facilitate computer processing and other operations, but, strictly speaking, digitizing simply means the conversion of analog source material into a numerical format; the decimal or any other number system that can be used instead. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitization)

As such, as you suspect, an [MP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) file contains a large set of digital information, ones and zeros if you like, that represent the sound intensity at very short intervals through the entire piece of music. The data is originally captured from the analog waveform using something called an [Analog to digital convertor (ADC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter). MP3 itself is a compressed format, a WAV file is raw samples.

Whatever is playing back the digitized file, decompresses it and uses those values to drive an amplifier with voltages, generated by what is called a [Digital to Analog Convertor (DAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter), which are recreated at the same rate as it was originally sampled during recording.

[image]

This actually produces a steppy waveform, however the steps are at such a high frequency compared to the original data that this distortion can be filtered out or is too high for the mechanics of the speaker to respond to or the human "ear" to notice.

I would not say binary is on our head though. It's more that our brains are not capable of distinguishing between things that happen continuously vs things that happen repeatedly at higher speeds. We see movie and TV projections as continuous movement even though we know that they are in fact a sequence of images being shown to us at a frequency that is faster than our brains can separate.

Comment: Thank You very Much ...although I am still confused but I think I know that the problem is I am confusing rather connecting everything ,from instruction set of microprocessor to compiler. I have to learn more or think more before asking the problem .

Comment: @NandaSinha yes, you have jumped into the deep end of the pool :) Keep studying and reading, you will get there, and learn to swim.

Comment: I feel I was asking about this question  sir https://superuser.com/questions/307116/how-does-a-cpu-know-what-commands-and-instructions-actually-mean

Comment: More specifically  "an interface between the abstract assembly instructions and the physical electrical logic in the processor." I just wanted to see how this interface is implemented/or works. (Electronically and Electrically in wires & signals).