# How does computer chip know what a 0 and a 1 is at base level?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, switches, integrated-circuit, microprocessor

I know there are some questions answered like this, and I have read them. I still have the same question though.

So from my understanding is that machine code is basically 0's and 1's. There are many switches that basically get turned on and off by when electricity is running through, its on (or is 1) and when no electricity it is off (or is 0).

We upload machine code so that the metal or what ever the chip on the board is comprised off, understands this and 0's and 1's. My question is how does this chip once it is built know to even recognize that we're saying 0's and 1's? How does the chip even know what a 0 or 1 is? How does it know that when switch is on to be assigning 1 to it and vise versa?

I know I cant just take a piece of metal(or what ever the chip is made of) and upload machine code it thinking that it will understand that I am trying to tell it that when switch is on to be assigned 1. How does this work?

This is one site I looked at:

[How does a computer recognize 0s and 1s?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250738/how-does-a-computer-recognize-0s-and-1s)

The problem is when the explanation gets to "The transistor can be turned on to enable access to the capacitor, either to charge it up and store a 1". So basically electricity goes through and the transistor is on and is charged and then stores a 1. But how does it know what a 1 is? How does it know how to interpret that 1 is associated with electricity charging the capacitor up?

As you can see, these are the questions I have. Any help would be great.

Comment: 'It' doesn't _know_ anything. We define electrical specifications that say (for example) a voltage <0.8V means logic 0, >2.8V means logic 1 and we build circuits that stick to those specifications. I think the term you're looking for is _logic levels_.

Comment: Ok so logic gates and lets say its >2.8v is 1, how does it get a 1 assigned? It doesn't know anything, I know that, but how does 1 get assigned just because an operator is true or false? I am being very specific. My question is how it 1 being assigned? Electricity goes through and fills up the capacitor and then magically a 1 appears? How is it getting 2.8v?

Comment: I think your question is actually quite vague. What does an _operator_ mean? What are you 'assigning'? Are you talking about DRAM?

Comment: I think this is a poor question due to being vague. Vote to close.

Comment: What in the world does "assigned" mean? Who is doing all of this assigning?

Comment: operator is what tangrs used ">", "<", ect. Assigning is meaning we put 0 or 1 there. My question is how? My question is not vague at all, its very specific.

Comment: Did you read [How is binary converted to electrical signals?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/25075/6334)

Comment: I did read that and it still doesn't answer my question. So according to this the switch is flipped and 1 is suppose to be there cause switch is flip in the transistor. Question remains the same as how it uploading or giving 1 to a switch being flipped based on the electrical signal?

Comment: After reading comments, it appears you are asking for an explanation of how transistors work, how they are combined to form logic gates, how those gates are combined to form complex logic circuits, and how those logic circuits are combined to make a useful computer. That's a course of study for a complete EE degree, not a few paragraphs of Q&A. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: After reading, I think you protest too much. How do *you* think the thought, "***flying pig***?" Does it matter to you that some people think it means a cape with pig legs stiffly outstretched and for some others that it means a flapping, winged pig?? You don't know why you think the way you do. But you do. A computer does NOT know why a 0 is a 0 or a 1 is a 1. And there are as many different creative ways of achieving that as there are imaginations. A computer can be YOU, emulating instructions, looking at pencil marks on paper. Etc. Fact is, various computers work various ways just fine.

Comment: @BobG. I think you're getting things mixed up. The less-than or greater-than is an electrical property of whatever circuit you've built (like the minimum voltage required to switch on a particular type of transistor). It's not like a operator in programming where the analog voltage is somehow 'compared' against a reference.

Comment: Whatever voltage causes the desired effect in the circuitry is what it considers that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of basic computer is comprised of "binary" elements, or [**flip-flops**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)). Or FF for short. The element has two states, "flip-left", and "flip-right". When the FF flops, "electricity flows" from one side to another in a fast, avalanche-like process, one side assumes high potential (voltage), the other assumes "low" voltage. Either side of FF can be considered as "right output", and all FFs are following this arbitrary convention.

As result, an information gets represented as "low voltage", and "high voltage", both somewhere in between the ground and supplying voltage. It is important to note that these two levels are fairly distinct, they don't have a continuous "analogish" spread of values. That determines the fundamental difference between analog and digital electronics. And the FF can stay in this state as long as the supply voltage is there, unless a special kick is applied so the FF can flip. These "storage elements" can be implemented in several different ways, but the principle is the same - their output assumes either a distinctive "high" level, or "low", with a noticeable gap between these two levels.

Once the levels are defined and distinct, there are elements that can discriminate between these two levels, just like a normal comparator. If a signal is above some threshold between "low" and "high", the result is amplified to "strong high". This would be a simple logical buffer. One can say that the output has "assigned" high level, or "1". Since the power supply usually is limited to certain level, 1.8V, 3.3V, or older 5V, the actual output voltage doesn't go too far, and stays within the same voltage "bin" as in the original flip-flop. So we have a consistency in voltage levels representing  "low" and "high", or "0s" and "1s".

If the output gets amplified in opposite direction, it will be called "inverter". The next in complexity is a "gate" that receives two input signals, so a certain combination of them results in "strong output". Look up [NOR gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) as a fundamental example.

So, a computer logic "knows" which is "0" and which is "1" by sensing the difference between two levels (say, with "buffers" as described above), and flipping other internal FFs into corresponding states if needed/instructed. The actual FFs are a bit more complicated than the one shown at the beginning of Wikipedia article, scroll down to more useful FFs called D-flops. They have "reset" signal allowing to put every FF into (known) initial state, and have "enable" inputs that allow to distribute/latch common signals with discretion.

The rest of a computer is simple - FFs are grouped into registers that are wired to buses of buffers, some functions (a bit more complex than NOR) are designed, clock is ticking, and when instruction codes are fetched from memory (similar kind of flip-flop arrays), sequences of logic operations lead to desired results.

Does this explanation address your concern?

Comment: Actually yes, this makes more sense than the other answers. The flip-flops based on electricity flow is what sold this answer. Thanks so much.

Comment: +1 despite it being a very specific/narrow answer to a very broad question because it seems to address the spirit of the original question.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't "know" anything, it just does what it does. An "on" transistor conducts, an "off" transistor doesn't. We build patterns out of the electrical components, in such a way that a certain pattern of high and low voltages *here* results in a different pattern of high and low voltages *there* a moment later. We call the low voltages 0 and the high voltages 1, but the components don't care what we call them.

We choose a representation of numbers as 0s and 1s, and then we build a circuit so that if we put the representation of a number A *here* and the representation of another number B *here*, then the representation of A+B comes out *there*, and we say that the component is doing addition, but all the electrons know is that they're following a potential gradient.

We hook things up so that when the user presses a button with the picture "7" on it, a collection of wires get high and low voltages forced on them in the pattern that we decided corresponds to the number 7. We hook other things up so that the voltages on another collection of wires light and extinguish small lamps in just the right pattern to make a picture of the number those wires represent. Now we've got ourselves... well, a calculator really, but we're on our way to a computer.

Comment: Ugh, everyone is against me and no one understands my question. This answer doesn't answer my question. You say "it just does what it does." That makes no sense. You also mention "We call the low voltages 0 and high voltages 1" , so how is 0 actually assigned? I know it is based on if electricity is not present that its considered 0 by us, but how does the it interpret electricity is not there and then puts 0 there?

Comment: @BobG. it doesn't. Whatever you're imagining that that sentence means, it doesn't happen anywhere.

Comment: What? Your just making me more confused now. Then why does a 0 or a 1 appear if it doesn't? How does this happen? So electricity fills it up and a 1 appears. How is the 1 appearing is my question.

Comment: @BobG. are you trying to ask "*why* do transistors conduct when you put one voltage on them, but not another"? Because no matter how big a microscope you get, you won't see any 1s appearing anywhere.

Comment: I can design a computer where 3 V means "1", or a computer where 5 V means "1". I can even design a computer where 0 V means 1 and 5 V means 0. I assign these meanings when I write the documentation for the computer. Then I carefully design the circuits so that when I want to NAND a 0 V signal and a 0 V signal, I get 5 V out, and so on for the different combinations of inputs.

Comment: Ok how does it process that 0v is coming through and to give 5v out? How does it display as the number?

Comment: Basically the way I am interpreting is that 0v is coming through and then the chip just gives 5volts like it knows what 5 volt is and its all magical. I know it is not magical. How is the 5 volt happening? There has to be some way that it like knows how to interpret yet it doesn't "know."

Comment: @BobG., You can google and find NAND gate circuit designs for TTL or CMOS very easily. If you want a NAND gate for my backwards logic design, just use the circuit that's normally called a NOR gate. If you want to know how one of these circuits works, you can ask a question about that, but please do some research first. It's very basic information that is found in numerous textbooks and online resources, and we generally don't take answers that rehash extremely well-known material.

Comment: For example if you look at the Wikipedia article [NAND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) you will find at least 4 different ways of making a NAND gate. They work because transistors have certain physical properties, not because they "know" what a voltage is or because of magic.

Comment: @BobG. the output goes to 5 volts and not some other value because a transistor is conducting between the 5-volt power supply and the output. No hermenuetics required.

Comment: @BobG. Suggested reading: Petzold's *Code*. :)

Comment: So I looked at NAND gate and same question. Here is quote from that site "produces an output which is false only if all its inputs are true" So how does it know an output which is true or false? Again I know it doesn't know anything. Also, how it is outputting? How does those gates work? I know it many site that explains the idea of gates but it never explains how the interpretation happens. How does the output just because the transistor conducts 5 volts? How does it just " know " its 5 volts?

Comment: There's no interpretation. The transistors are simply wired in a way that has the behaviour where if you have 5V on both the inputs, the output is connected to GND else, the output is connected to 5V. Look up a diagram of a CMOS/PMOS/NMOS NAND gate if you want to see how the transistors can be wired up to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: @BobG. Also, [NAND2Tetris](http://nand2tetris.org/) seems like a good place to start if you want to learn how computers work from first principles.

Comment: @BobG. I think you're almost there. First step is to accept that a a computer can be made out of logic gates. Your next step is to understand how a logic gate works. Research "transistor NAND" gate and you'll see that. Afterwards research how a transistor works and you'll be done.

Comment: @BobG. how does a light switch know that when you push the switch up, you want a light to turn on? It doesn't, it's just built so that in one position it connects the lamp to the power supply, and in one position it doesn't. That might seem like I'm trivializing things, but you can build AND, OR, and XOR gates out of lightswitches if you want. Combine the switch with an electromagnet so that it can be turned on and off by an electrical signal, and you have a relay. Make a relay very small, very fast, and a bit more quantum, and you have a transistor. Gates still work the same.

Comment: @BobG Look up how transistors work. In the case of a "N-channel MOSFET", it conducts if the voltage on the gate terminal is higher than the voltage on the source terminal by a specific amount (often in the range of 3 volts or so). You can easily use one N-channel MOSFET and one resistor to make a circuit whose output is 0v if the input is 5v, and whose output is 5v if the input is 0v, for example.